# Adobe Air Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder, sandbox

```
Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.: SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()
```

Hi all,

I have an air project that I am trying to run via a terminal using run-air command. If I run it in flash builder it seems to run with no errors, but after using a makefile to build the project and then run the code via run-air in the terminal I get the above error. Before I Was getting the same error and put a try catch around the code, however, I can't do that in this part of the code and don't want to put a try catch everywhere I get this error. I would rather just fix it. It seems to get called whenever my code is trying to access a class via a swc or import.

Anyone have suggestions?

I have tried:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

which through the same error, so I put a try catch around it and now it moves on and I Get the above error when I Try to load a swc.

Also we are adding the src folder to the class that is throwing the error above via the compiler properties (we are doing unit tests) and using a makefile to build the project. If we didn't put it in compiler properties the class never seems to get picked up.